# How to change input text focus border

Tags: html, css, sass

when clicking on the input text a golden border is showing up, I tried to change its color using :focus selector but it is not working:

```
HTML:

<input
                        type="text"
                        id="username"
                        ref={userRef}
                        autoComplete="off"
                        onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
                        value={user}
                        required
                        name="username"
                    />
```

```
CSS

.body input[type="text"] {
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  &:active {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  &:focus {
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
  }
}
```

[image: showing the golden border]

[image: showing the normal border]

Comment: You did not post a [example], but it is likely what you are seeing is not [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border), but [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).

Comment: i thinks it is outline not border, you should change border to outline in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information that you gave is a little bit hard to reproduce, but I guess it's actually the `outline` that is being changed, and not the border.
You can try this instead:

```
.body input[type="text"] {
  &:hover {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
  }
  &:active {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

can u please try this css:

```
  input[type=text] {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
      outline: none;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:focus {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```